# Laravel Convert collection to array

Tags: arrays, laravel-5.4

I have the following function in my controller

```php
$tasksinprogress = Auth::user()->tasks()->whereHas('taskinteractions', function ($query) {
    $query->where('status', 'In Progress');
})->get();
```

when I print $tasksinprogress, the result is the following:

```js
[{"id":44,"project_id":1,"task_type_id":3,"related_block":14,"created_by":1,"assigned_to":4,"task_priority":5,"start_date":"2017-04-12","due_date":"2017-04-27","comments":"Test Task","status":null,"created_at":"2017-04-11 10:53:42","updated_at":"2017-04-11 10:53:42"}]
```

Now, if i try to extract the id like this `{{ $tasksinprogress->id }}`, i get the error `Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.`. if i do this `{{ $tasksinprogress['0']->id }}` i can extract the properties of the collection. The method get() returns a collection, in this specific case it's a collection of only one array. The result of the print is :

```js
{"id":44,"project_id":1,"task_type_id":3,"related_block":14,"created_by":1,"assigned_to":4,"task_priority":5,"start_date":"2017-04-12","due_date":"2017-04-27","comments":"Test Task","status":null,"created_at":"2017-04-11 10:53:42","updated_at":"2017-04-11 10:53:42"}
```

It works fine when my array has only one dimension. How do i go around this problem, i want to do a @foreach loop to display each task in a sepparate block.
I have tried adding `->toArray()` after the get method, but got na error, something about Array to String conversion.

**Collapsible Panel, after the comments**

```php
@foreach ($tasksinprogress->sortByDesc('due_date') as $inprogress)
    <div class="container">
      <div class="panel-group">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:#d4f79e ">
            <h5 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse{{ $$inprogress->id }}">
                <span class="">
                  Task # {{ str_pad($inprogress->id,4,'0', STR_PAD_LEFT) }}
                </span>
                <span class="">
                  <small><b>{{ $tasktype = DB::table('tasktypes')->where('id','=', $inprogress->task_type_id )->value('task_type') }} for block {{ $related_block = DB::table('chapters')->where('id','=', $inprogress->related_block)->value('description') }}</b></small>
                </span>
                <span class="pull-right">
                  {{ $inprogress->due_date }} 
                </span>
              </a>
            </h5>
          </div>
          <div id="collapse{{ $inprogress->id }}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
              {{ Form::open(array('url' => '/tasks/changetaskstatus')) }}
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="task_id">Task #</label>
                    <input id="task_id" type="text" name="task_id" class="form-control" placeholder="" readonly="readonly" value="{{ str_pad($inprogress->id,4,'0', STR_PAD_LEFT)}}">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="tasktype">Task Type</label>
                    <input id="tasktype" type="text" name="tasktype" class="form-control" placeholder="" readonly="readonly" value="{{ $tasktype = DB::table('tasktypes')->where('id','=', $inprogress->task_type_id )->value('task_type') }}">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="related_block">Related Block</label>
                    <input id="related_block" type="text" name="related_block" class="form-control" placeholder="" readonly="readonly" value="{{ $related_block = DB::table('chapters')->where('id','=', $inprogress->related_block)->value('description') }}">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">    
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="comments">Comments</label>
                      <textarea id="comments" name="comments" class="form-control" placeholder="Comments" rows="2"></textarea>
                      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <br/>
                  <div class="well well-sm"><small>Current status:</small> {{ $currentstatus = DB::table('task_interactions')->where('task_id','=', $inprogress->id )->pluck('status')->last() }}
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="status">Change Status</label><br/>
                    <select name="status" class="form-control" data-title="status">
                        <option selected disabled>Select Status</option>
                        <option>  Unassigned</option>
                        <option>  Assigned</option>
                        <option>  In Progress</option>
                        <option>  Paused</option>
                        <option>  Finished</option>
                        <option>  Cancelled</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-3 offset-md-9">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save" aria-hidden="true"></span> Apply Changes</button>
              </div>
              </div>
              {{ Form::close() }}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

->get() method will always give you collection of objects even if it has only one document in result.

Basically if you always want to get one match from query, you can use :

```
$tasksinprogress = Auth::user()->tasks()->whereHas('taskinteractions', function ($query) {
            $query->where('status', 'In Progress');
        })->first();
```

Using static [0] index is not a good practice.

Also now you can directly use :

```
$id = $tasksinprogress->id
```

If you want array :

```
$id = $id = $tasksinprogress->toArray()[id]
```

If you want to get all and check if it returns one of not do folliwng in your blade :

```
$tasksinprogress = Auth::user()->tasks()->whereHas('taskinteractions', function ($query) {
                $query->where('status', 'In Progress');
            })->get();

if($tasksinprogress->count() > 0){
//your loic
}
else{
//your msg for empty result
}
```

Comment: I might be doing something really wrong… 
If I do this: 
`@foreach ($tasksinprogress as $task)
<li>{{ $task->id }} | {{ $task->project_id }}</li>
@endforeach` it works.
Passing the result to a collapsible panel (previously used and working) returns an error
`Undefined variable: [{"id":44,"project_id":1,"task_type_id":3,"related_block":14........"}] `

Maybe the error is in the collapsible panel code

Comment: Can you add the blade collapsible panel here? I guess its where the things might are going wrong

Comment: i have changed the question to add the code for the collapsible panel

Comment: got it! one of the calls to the variable was like this `$$inprogress`.... It's solved now